# Oracle APEX - How do I sync local files with my laptop?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We have started using Oracle APEX at my university. And we're working on it with a local environment (had to install Oracle 11g Database and Oracle APEX locally). There was also an option for an online workspace, but I've found that it is quite slow.

My question is: how can I synchronize the files (workspaces, applications etc) with my main desktop at home and my laptop at university. I would use Google Drive to put the files on, but what I need to figure out is where the files that I can synchronize are located.

I'm using:
Windows 10, 64 bit.
Oracle Database Express Edition 11g.
Oracle Application Express, version 5.0.4.

If there is any additional information, please let me know.

Comment: You can export the workspace from within APEX if I'm not mistaken. This is the way an APEX application is moved from test to production.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I'll use this!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, you can export the workspace, but this will not take the associated schema's with it (ie tables, data, packages). It won't even take the applications with it. Those will need to be exported individually. Though: yes, it's best that if you go with constant export-import you better take an export of the workspace and import it remotely so the ID's will match so apex will not complain about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've really not taken an easy route while trying to make things easier for yourself.
Apex resides in the database itself. There are no "files" except the actual "images" directory. The applications you create are in the database. Your data itself will reside in a schema in that database.
If you want to move between 2 databases all the time, it means you'll have to do all the DDL and DML you do your local schema another time on the remote location. You'll need to export and import the applications.
You could use datapump to always take an export of the entire schema (not the apex schema!) and then import that on the remote (but has to be run on the machine itself, not from sqlplus, so you'll need access on both locations for this). Applications will have to be exported and imported individually.
You'd have been served better by using the online service, or use a virtual machine on say an external hard drive.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I've got a much clearer understanding of how APEX works now, thank you.